# Dynamically import and create class instance

Tags: python

With my python application, I have 40 modules (classes) which contain a parser for some text. In my function I only want to instanciate and use a particular module. These are all sorted in the database.

I am at the point now where I know my parser, and have both the python file name and class I want to import and create

However.... How do you actually do this in python?

eg;

```
file_name = 'lex_parser'
class_name = 'LexParser'
```

how can I do....

```
from {file_name} import {class_name}
Parser = {class_name}()
```

Follow what I mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
file_name = 'lex_parser'
class_name = 'LexParser'

Parser = getattr(__import__(file_name), class_name)
```

Note that `file_name` must not contain `.py`.

This won't work if the module is within a package because `__import__` would return the top level package. In that case you can do this:

```
import sys

file_name = 'parsers.lex_parser'
class_name = 'LexParser'

__import__(file_name)
Parser = getattr(sys.modules[file_name], class_name)
```

This will work in both cases and is recommeded by the `__import__` function [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#__import__).

In both examples `Parser` is a class which you have to instantiate as normally:

```
parser = Parser()
```

Answer (score 3):

How about something like this:

```
module = __import__('my_module')
if hasattr(module, 'ClassName'):
    ClassName = module.ClassName
    my_object = ClassName()
```

Comment: Looks promising, however I get,     

ClassName = module.ClassName
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ClassName'

Comment: @Wizzard The identifiers I wrote is just examples, and you might have to use `getattr` to get the classes.